# Weight for weight from CodeWars

Tags: javascript, sorting, lexicographic

The question is:

> "My friend John and I are members of the "Fat to Fit Club (FFC)". John
> is worried because each month a list with the weights of members is
> published and each month he is the last on the list which means he is
> the heaviest.
>
> I am the one who establishes the list so I told him: "Don't worry any
> more, I will modify the order of the list". It was decided to
> attribute a "weight" to numbers. The weight of a number will be from
> now on the sum of its digits.
>
> For example 99 will have "weight" 18, 100 will have "weight" 1 so in
> the list 100 will come before 99. Given a string with the weights of
> FFC members in normal order can you give this string ordered by
> "weights" of these numbers?"

Example

> "56 65 74 100 99 68 86 180 90" ordered by numbers weights becomes: "100 180 90 56 65 74 68 86 99"
> When two numbers have the same "weight", let us class them as if they
> were strings (alphabetical ordering) and not numbers: 100 is before
> 180 because its "weight" (1) is less than the one of 180 (9) and 180
> is before 90 since, having the same "weight" (9), it comes before as a
> string.
>
> All numbers in the list are positive numbers and the list can be
> empty.

This is the code I have so far:

```
function sumOfParts(num) {
  return num.split('').reduce((a, b) => parseInt(a) + parseInt(b), 0)
} 

function orderWeight(string) {
  return string.split(' ').sort().sort((a,b) => sumOfParts(a) - sumOfParts(b)).join(' ')
}
```

The code words on strings even with two consecutive numbers with the same value but when 3+ numbers with the same sum are added it starts to break....
Here are some strings that broke it:

> Expected: '112 14 170 233100 63 29 65 138 156 67 77 79 324612 144435
> 143275 335392 477504 460549 96194 281479 347984', instead got: '112 14
> 170 63 233100 29 65 156 138 67 77 79 324612 144435 143275 335392
> 477504 460549 96194 281479 347984'
>
> Expected: '200 113 41 114 25 52 109 155 83 76 161330 59 450231 274111
> 93131 440830 432353 274292 320986 371567 29858', instead got: '200 41
> 113 114 52 25 109 83 155 76 59 161330 450231 274111 93131 440830
> 432353 274292 320986 371567 29858'

Been stuck on this one longer then I would like to admit lol

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a single sort and a sorting by string for same sums.

```js
function sumOfParts(num) {
    return num.split('').reduce((a, b) => a + +b, 0)
} 

function orderWeight(string) {
    return string
        .split(' ')
        .sort((a, b) => sumOfParts(a) - sumOfParts(b) || a > b || -(a < b))
        .join(' ');
}

console.log('out', orderWeight('112 14 170 63 233100 29 65 156 138 67 77 79 324612 144435 143275 335392 477504 460549 96194 281479 347984'));
console.log('exp', '112 14 170 233100 63 29 65 138 156 67 77 79 324612 144435 143275 335392 477504 460549 96194 281479 347984');


console.log('out', orderWeight('200 41 113 114 52 25 109 83 155 76 59 161330 450231 274111 93131 440830 432353 274292 320986 371567 29858'));
console.log('exp', '200 113 41 114 25 52 109 155 83 76 161330 59 450231 274111 93131 440830 432353 274292 320986 371567 29858');
```

Comment: Does this "a + +b" cover the strings into Ints automatically? Do we not need a parseInt or Number(a)

Comment: @mrahma04, the [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) converts the value to a number.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is such an elegant solution. Is '||' the OR operator in the sort method? Trying to understand the logic of the sort method...I get the first part...sumOfParts(a) - sumOfParts(b)...how is the rest evaluated...|| a > b || -(a < b))

Comment: Also do you not need to convert 'a' as well to a number...as in...+a + +b

Comment: @mrahma04the expression is separated by [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) and if a part between returns zero or any other falsy value the next part is evaluated. the part `a > b || -(a < b)` works for strings and numbers, but if string, it sorts by string and with numbers it sorts by numbers. in short it returns `true`, if the `a` is smaller than `b` and if greater, it negates `true` and returns `-1`. `reduce` starts with zero and therefore `a` is always a number.

Comment: @mrahma04, `|| (a > b ? 1 : -1)` also works instead of `|| a > b || -(a < b)`. This part is for sorting the strings (of numbers) alphabetically. (These 2 variations are not exactly the same, because they return different things when `a === b`. However, this does not matter for this problem since the resulting array will look the same.)